# Knowing the fan speeds (RPM) corresponding to levels 0-7 in the thinkfan configuration file

Tags: 22.04, configuration, thinkpad, thinkfan

I'm trying to configure `thinkfan` on Ubuntu 22.04.2.
But I'm wondering; to which speeds actually correspond the "levels" (first of the three columns of numbers) in the `thinkfan` config file?

E.g.:

```
$ grep -A10 levels: /etc/thinkfan.conf 

levels:
  - [0, 0, 45]
  - [1, 43, 48]
  - [2, 46, 51]
  - [3, 49, 54]
  - [4, 51, 60]
  - [5, 58, 65]
  - [6, 63, 72]
  - [7, 70, 82]
  - ["level full-speed", 77, 32767]
```

From `man thinkfan.conf`:

```
levels:    Maps temperatures to fan speeds. A “simple mapping” just specifies one temperature as
           the lower and upper bound (respectively) for a given fan speed.
           In a “detailed mapping”, the upper and lower bounds are specified for each driver/sensor
           configured under sensors:. This mode should be used when thinkfan is monitoring multiple
           devices that can tolerate different amounts of heat.
```

and:

```
FAN SPEEDS
      The levels: section specifies a list of fan speeds with associated lower and upper
      temperature bounds. If temperature(s) drop below the lower bound, thinkfan switches
      to the previous level, and if the upper bound is reached, thinkfan switches to the
      next level.

   Simple Syntax
      In the simplified form, only one temperature is specified as an upper/lower limit
      for a given fan speed. In that case, the lower-bound and upper-bound are compared
      only to the  highest temperature found among all configured sensors. All other
      temperatures are ignored. This mode is suitable for small systems (like laptops)
      where there is only one device (e.g. the CPU) whose temperature needs to be
      controlled, or where the required fan behaviour is similar enough for all
      heat-generating devices.

      levels:
        - [ fan-speed, lower-bound, upper-bound ]
        - ...

   Detailed Syntax
      This mode is suitable for more complex systems, with devices that have different
      temperature ratings. For example, many modern CPUs and GPUs can deal with
      temperatures above 80°C on a daily basis, whereas a hard disk will die quickly
      if it reaches such temperatures. In detailed mode, upper and lower temperature
      limits are specified for each sensor individually:

      levels:
        - speed: fan-speed
          lower_limit: [ l1, l2, ... ]
          upper_limit: [ u1, u2, ... ]
        - ...

   Values
      fan-speed   The possible speed values are different depending on which fan driver
                  is used.

                  For a hwmon fan, fan-speed is a numeric value ranging from 0 to 255,
                  corresponding to the PWM values accepted by the various kernel drivers.

                  For a tpacpi fan on Lenovo/IBM ThinkPads and some other Lenovo laptops
                  (see SENSORS & FAN DRIVERS above), numeric values and strings can be used.
                  The numeric values range from 0 to 7.
                  The string values take the form "level lvl-id", where lvl-id may be a
                  value from 0 to 7, auto, full-speed or disengaged. The numeric values
                  0 to 7 correspond to the regular fan speeds used by the firmware,
                  although many firmwares don't even use level 7. The value "level auto"
                  gives control back to the firmware, which may be useful if the fan
                  behavior only needs to be changed for certain specific temperature
                  ranges (usually at the high and low end of the range). The values
                  "level full-speed" and "level disengaged" take the fan speed control
                  away from the  firmware, causing the fan to slowly ramp up to an absolute
                  maximum that can be achieved within electrical limits. Note that this
                  will run the fan out of specification and cause increased wear,
                  though it may be helpful to combat thermal throttling.

      l1, l2, ...

      u1, u2, ... The lower and upper limits refer to the sensors in the same order in
                  which they were found when processing the sensors: section (see SENSOR
                  & FAN DRIVERS above). For the first level entry, the lower_limit may
                  be omitted, and for the last one, the upper_limit may be omitted.
                  For all levels in between, the lower limits must overlap with the upper
                  limits of the previous level, to make sure the entire temperature range
                  is covered and that there is some hysteresis between speed levels.
```

especially this sentence: `The numeric values 0 to 7 correspond to the regular fan speeds used by the firmware`

How could I know about the fan speeds (in [RPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_per_minute)) corresponding to this 0-7 values?

Answer (score 0):

Those values corresponding to the numeric values 0 to 7 are not standardized, so you can see in the documentation of your system firmware or you can use a tool like sensors to see the fan speed and temperature.

You can install the `lm-sensors` package then run `sensors` to get those informations and even modify them then monitor the result